# Bitbucket: How to not see pull requests that I have already approved

Tags: bitbucket

Under the **Pull Requests to Review** section of Bitbucket, it shows all of the pull requests that I am a reviewer of. How do I alter this so that when I approve a pull request, it no longer shows up under this section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org), then there's an option on the dashboard for this:

[image]

Look to the right of the "Your work" label, and just above the list of pull requests, for the option.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Thanks